# Google Maps Content Box OnLoad

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How do I make my code show the google content box as soon as it loads? I can make it work for on click but not when page loads. Any advice?

Here's my code for on mouse click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onload function, after initializing the map:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
```

(assumes marker is in scope for the call)

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to do the exact same on document load. Assuming you don't use any libraries (like jQuery) you can simply alter your body tag to call a javascript function

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

that contains the above code, ie

```
function myFunction() {
   marker = [ your logic ]     
   map = [ your logic ]  
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
```